# How to map response.body to multiple List?

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically I have 2 `List<Object>`:

`List<Feed> feeList` & `List<Comment> commentList`

then when I launch my app, I automatically call the method to fetch the data from my API to populate the main `List` which is the `List<Feed> feeList`.

My goal is to populate these 2 List so that I don't have to call for another API just to populate the other list which is the `List<Comment> commentList`.

So I experimented and added `commentList = data['comments']
          .map<Comment>((json) => Comment.fromJson(json))
          .toList();`

When I debug, I did `print(res.body);` and then my response **FROZE** to a certain index.

Is it actually possible?

here's my code:

```
Future<List<Feed>> getFeedAll() async {
    var res = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(APIServices.httpDomain + APIServices.postGetAll),
        headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + Constants.token});

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var data = json.decode(res.body);
      print("$data");
      feedList = data.map<Feed>((json) => Feed.fromJson(json)).toList();
      commentList = data['comments']
          .map<Comment>((json) => Comment.fromJson(json))
          .toList();
    }

    print(res.body);

    return feedList;
  }
```

Comment: could you post Feed class, Comment class and json string you get from api?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely missing some null validation in you model class. Without knowing your model I assume you have lists that could be null and thus missing from the response:

Look for `cast` in your model and handle `null` values:

For example:

```
mystringlist= json['mystringlist'].cast<String>();
```

Change to:

```
mystringlist = json['mystringlist'] != null
        ? json['mystringlist'].cast<String>()
        : List<String>();
```